# Remove duplicate and count them in row

Tags: php, arrays, count, duplicates, row

I would like to delete duplicate entries and then count them to display them next to my entries in my php ROW

I've already tried this:

```
<?php                                       
foreach (array_unique($events) as $eventorga) {                                     
$eventorgan = $eventorga['organizer'];                                      
echo $eventorga['organizer'].'</br>';                                       
}                                       
?>
```

But an error: Array to string conversion is returned to me

```
<?php
foreach ($events as $eventorga) {
echo $eventorga['organisateur'].'</br>';
}
?>
```

Currently, my code returns this result:

```
Holyblood
Nessy
Pokégaia
Sorrow
JOHN
Holyblood
```

(From my MYSQL database)

I would like the return to be that:

```
Holyblood - 2
Nessy - 1
Pokégaia - 1
Sorrow - 1
JOHN - 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$eventResposne = array();

    array_walk($eventorga,function($responses,$index) use( &$eventResposne){
              if(isset($eventResposne[$responses['organisateur']])){
                       $eventResposne[$responses['organisateur']] = $eventResposne[$responses['organisateur']] + 1;
              }else{
                    $eventResposne[$responses['organisateur']] = 1;

              }       
    });
```

It will return an array like {'Holyblood':2,'Nessy':1,...}.
Now use $eventResposne array to print the desired pattern.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
But the error "Warning: array_walk() expects parameter 1 to be array" is returned to me.

For information, I recover my data from the database via 
`sql = "SELECT id, title, description, organiser, orgaavailable, donator, start, end, color FROM events";
$req = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$req->execute();

$events = $req->fetchAll();`

Comment: It is already mentioned in your question that you have an array variable $eventorga so i used the same array variable.

Your array must be like 

$eventorga = [['organisateur'=>'Holyblood'],['organisateur'=>'Nessy'],...]

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$events =  [
            "Holyblood",
            "Nessy",
            "Pokégaia",
            "Sorrow",
            "JOHN",
            "Holyblood"
        ];
$eventCounts = [];
foreach ($events as $key => $eventorga) {
    if(!isset($eventCounts[$eventorga]))
        $eventCounts[$eventorga] = 0;
    $eventCounts[$eventorga]++   ;     

}
foreach ($eventCounts as $eventName => $eventCount) {
    echo $eventName . ' - ' . $eventCount . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works with fixed data!
Do you know how I can automate this by directly integrating data from my database?

This data is recovered via 

    `sql = "SELECT id, title, description, organiser, orgaavailable, donator, start, end, color FROM events";
    $req = $bdd->prepare($sql);
    $req->execute();
    $events = $req->fetchAll();`